# How can i Turn iMac (OS x) into ibeacon?

Tags: macos, ibeacon

I know that iOS7 device act as an iBeacon. how can I could turn my iMac into an iBeacon for testing purposes.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question belongs to apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @theSoft - no, it does not.  It is a programming task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a lot of success using a Bluetooth LE dongle (cost $12) and a virtual machine. Was super fast to install and set up and very accurate - perfect 'test bed'. Got a dongle at a local store - the hardest part of this is actually going out and buying one!

You can find instructions at Radiant, here:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/virtual.html

We tried to create a beacon natively without a dongle but haven't come up with a way to do so.

Comment: The link is not working.